# How to enable Databricks Delta feature

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

Upgraded my Azure Databricks from standard to primary, trying to start using Databricks Delta:

```
create table t
using delta
as select * from test_db.src_data;
```

> Databricks Delta is not enabled in your account. Please reach out to
>   your account manager to talk about using Delta;

I'm the account manager but can not find this setting. Where is it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. using Spark SQL Context in `ipynb` and `scala` notebooks :

`sql("SET spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled=true")`

`sql("SET spark.databricks.delta.merge.joinBasedMerge.enabled = true")`

2. In `SQL dbc notebooks`:

`SET spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled=true`

`SET spark.databricks.delta.merge.joinBasedMerge.enabled`

3. When you wanna `default the cluster to support Delta` , while spinning up the cluster on UI in the `last column` in the `parameters for Environment variables`

just this line : `spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled=true`

4. Or the last and the final fun part. When you spin your cluster `Select 5.0 or above` we should have Delta enabled by default for these guys.

And finally welcome to Databricks Delta :)

Also, Just to help you out with your code there it should look like this

`%sql create table t as select * from test_db.src_data
USING DELTA
PARTITIONED BY (YourPartitionColumnHere)
LOCATION "/mnt/data/path/to/the/location/where/you/want/these/parquetFiles/to/be/present"`

Comment: Thank you! Already started using with 5.0. Excellent feature!